# Contact form 7 not reading input values

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

This is the first time i face this strange issue .. i have contact form and i receive an email from it but input variable like [fullname] are not replaced with input value inserted by the user.

[image]

[image]

Here is my form code in admin panel

```
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
[text* fullname id:name class:form-control placeholder"Please enter your name"]
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
[email* email id:email class:form-control placeholder"Please enter your Email Address"]
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
[text* phone id:phone class:form-control placeholder"Please enter your phone number"]
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
[text* subject id:subject class:form-control placeholder"Please enter message subject"]
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    [textarea* message id:message rows:4 class:form-control placeholder"We are in love with details, feel free to share as much details as you would love to. We respond to messages in 12 hours or lesser time - for quick response, please leave your phone number so that we can call you back."]    
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
[submit class:default-btn class:btn-block "Send"]
</div>
```

Comment: crosscheck the field names in ur message body under mail panel.